# Proguard Not Obfuscating Everything in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, obfuscation

Proguard is not obfuscating 95% of my code for some reason.

Only select classes and method names are obfuscated, I can't seem to find any pattern. Anyone know why this is the case?

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 and want to obfuscate my code with Proguard, I have it enabled for debug and release builds.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Here's my proguard rules file:

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*,!code/allocation/variable

-dontwarn org.jdom2.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.google.common.collect.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**

# ------------------------------------------
# Crashlytics
# ------------------------------------------
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

-dontwarn com.viewpagerindicator.LinePageIndicator

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { public *; }
-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Exceptions

-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.**
-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class okio.** { *; }
```

I would like to obfuscate as much as possible, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are a [number of questions about this](https://www.google.com/search?q=proguard+not+obfuscating&oq=progruard+not&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3220j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) already. Have you gone through them.

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't post here. Most of them deal with debug mode or keepclass/keepclasswithname attributes, which I'm not using.

Comment: I am facing the same problem ..my all code can be decompiled easily .all my classes and methods can be seen easily ...proguard doesnot changing the name also... have you got any thing regarding it...I want to know if -keep method prevents the proguard to change my class and method names...I want to keep everything that I typed in my code because sometimes somewhere button listener stop working or usb manager stop responding or app crashes again and again....